# Write multiple lists of different length to a csv in python each having different columnnames

Tags: python, list, csv, file-io, file-handling

I have two lists:

```
A = ['Apple', 'Dog']
B = ['Cat', 'OWL', 'PEACOCK']

I want output to a csv as :

A

Apple
Dog

B

Cat
OWL
PEACOCK
```

How can I output these two lists to a csv. I tried with zip but it's
only meant for same sized lists

Answer (score 0):

You can add a blank item to list `A`, and then export it using `pandas`. Pandas uses a data structure called a DataFrame, but the columns must be equal length. The output .csv file will not show the blank data cell.

```
import pandas as pd
A = ['Apple', 'Dog']
B = ['Cat', 'OWL', 'PEACOCK']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':A})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':B})
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).to_csv('myfile.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: That's not a good solution when I will be dealing with multiple lists

Comment: Sure it is. You just have to expand it for your use case. Don't expect StackOverflow to do all the work for you. You can also look at the packages `xlsxwriter` and `csv`, but `pandas` is much more versatile for csv/dataframe manipulation.

Comment: It's not an optimized way to check the length of each list when I have hundreds of lists and append blank items for each. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: import pandas as pd
A = ['Apple', 'Dog']
B = ['Cat', 'OWL', 'PEACOCK']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':A})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':B})
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).to_csv('myfile.csv', index = False)